# Laravel 5.5 Queued?

Tags: artisan, laravel-5.5

Estou começando em Laravel, e instalei 5.5 e após exceutar este comando

```
php artisan make:command MyCommand --queued
```

O erro é o seguinte

> The "--queued" option does not exist.

Lendo um pouco mais, o comando existe no `5.1`.

Qual é o comando correto para o 5.5?

Comment: Não existe esse comando na criaçãode `command` eu pelo menos não vi na documentação, se por acaso viu poste o link!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, não encontrei na documentação. Varias videos na internet utilizam este comando nas versões anteriores, eu mesmo instalei uma versão anterior e funcionou. Não estou encontrando como utilizar este comando no Laravel 5.5.

Comment: Eu não testei esse comando, mas, nem precisa utilizar... para que utilizar isso ??? o que vai mudar?

Comment: Agilidade, o arquivo é criado com as interfaces e treats.

Answer (score 1):

A opção `--queued` foi definida na [versão 5.0 do Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues#basic-usage) e já foi definida como obsoleta na [versão 5.1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#writing-job-classes), onde passou-se a criar *Jobs*. A partir desta versão todos os *Jobs* criados são *queued* por padrão e a opção foi removida completamente (não encontrei em que versão exatamente isso aconteceu).

Na versão 5.5 e mais atuais você deve utilizar o comando:

```
$ php artisan make:job <nome>
```

Como [descrito na documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#generating-job-classes).

Ver mais em:

- [Laravel 5.5. artisan command queued](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47728379/1452488)
- [The “--queued” option does not exist in Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48239704/1452488)